# store posts_id of category into a varable?

Tags: posts, categories

I have ten posts in my query that belong in three categories: cat-a,cat-b,cat-c.

I'm looking for a way to store $posts_ids from each category into a variable.

Say for example, if three posts are in "category-a" then store those posts_ids in a variable.

Cat-a
Post 1 ID->435
Post 2 ID->477
Post 3 ID->488
$idcata = 435,477,488

Cat-b
Post 1 ID->87
Post 2 ID->32
$idcatb = 87,32

Cat-c
Post 1 ID->876
$idcatc = 876

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the posts related to each category you need to use `get_posts( $args )` function and in `$args` you can add your category_id

```
$args = array ( 
    'post_type'   => 'post',    
    'category'    => $cat_ID,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$my_posts = get_posts( $args ); // return array of posts

// storing all post ID in an array
foreach( $my_posts as $my_post ) {
    $post_cat_name[] = $my_post['ID'];
}
```

So in `$post_cat_name` it will store all the post id related to your `$cat_ID`

If you want these to be done for 3 `$cat_id`, then you can loop the above code for 3 `$cat_id` and you can use `$post_cat_name` array as `2D array`.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array. Error is in area: `// storing all post ID in an array
foreach( $my_posts as $my_post ) {
    $post_cat_name[] = $my_post['ID'];
}`